# Function to return the acronym of a string

Tags: c#

How can I write a function which given an input string, passes back the acronym for the string using only If/Then/Else, simple String functions, and Looping syntax (not use the Split( ) function or its equivalent)?

String s_input, s_acronym

s_input = "Mothers against drunk driving"

s_acronym = f_get_acronym(s_input)

print "acronym = " + s_acronym

/* acronym = MADD */

My code is here. just looking to see if I could get better solution

```
static string f_get_acronym(string s_input)
{
    string s_acronym = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s_input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0 && s_input[i].ToString() != " ")
        {
            s_acronym += s_input[i];
            continue;
        }

        if (s_input[i - 1].ToString() == " " && s_input[i].ToString() != " ")
        {
            s_acronym += s_input[i];
        }
    }

    return s_acronym.ToUpper();
}
```

Comment: If any examples and what have your tried are added to question, it would help to make your question more clear.

Comment: Just the first letter of each word?

Comment: @MaheshChand just edited the question

Comment: This is not a "do my homework" service. Do your own homework. If you have problems, show what you have tried and ask a specific question.

Comment: @MaheshChand Well I actually did this, but I was looking for different solutions to compare the performance. I will edit and put my code in

Comment: If you have a coding problem, you are good here. If your code works and you want to know how you can improve it, please head over to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Please read their tour and site guidelines first, if you just copy your post over, it will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is the way to go in C#. I know you only wanted simple functions, but I want to put this here for any further readers who shall be directed on the right path. ;)

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?:\s*(?<first>\w))\w+");
var matches = regex.Matches("Mother against druck driving");
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.Write(match.Groups["first"].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static string f_get_acronym(string s_input)
{
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s_input))
            return string.Empty;
        string accr = string.Empty;
        accr += s_input[0];
        while (s_input.Length > 0)
        {
            int index = s_input.IndexOf(' ');
            if (index > 0)
            {
                s_input = s_input.Substring(index + 1);
                if (s_input.Length == 0)
                    break;
                accr += s_input[0];
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        return accr.ToUpper();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```
public static string Acronym(string input)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    char last = ' ';

    foreach(var c in input)
    {
        if(char.IsWhiteSpace(last))
        {
            result += c;              
        }
        last = c;
    }

    return result.ToUpper();
}
```

Best practice says you should use a `StringBuilder` when adding to a string in a loop though. Don't know how long your acronyms are going to be.

Answer (score -2):

Your best way to do so would be to set up a loop to loop over every letter. If it is the first letter in the string, OR the first letter after a space, add that letter to a temp string, which is returned at the end.

eg (basic c++)

```
string toAcronym(string sentence)
{
    string acronym = "";
    bool wasSpace = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)
    {
        if (wasSpace == true)
        {
            if (sentence[i] != ' ')
            {
                wasSpace = false;
                acronym += toupper(sentence[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                wasSpace = true; 
            }
        }
        else if (sentence[i] == ' ')
        {
            wasSpace = true;
        }
    }
    return acronym;
}
```

This could be further improved by checking to make sure the letter to add to the acronym is a letter, and not a number / symbol. OR...

If it is the first letter in the string, add it to the acronym. Then, run a loop for "find next of" a space. Then, add the next character. Continuously loop the "find next of" space until it returns null / eof / end of string, then return.

Comment: This is the worst possible way to to this in a high level language like C#.

Comment: OP wasn't looking for the best way to do it (if they were, they'd use Split()). Just a different way using simple commands. Can it be written better? Certainly. Does it answer the question? I'd argue yes.

Comment: I'd argue the best way is Regex, but I am sorry as I am the one that misread the question. I will upvote as soon as I can.